# text box using jquery

Tags: jquery

Below code is used to delete text box.I have used **x**.I need to insert a image here and i need to place 3 text boxes in same line.This is like stack overflow.

Comment: You still have table cell end tags in your code... make sure you have valid code first. How did you add the images?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I do not have table tag in my code,above i have used div tag.For images,i used like this img src="path"

Comment: @raam: You have `</td>` in your code above, which are table cell end tags. And `$(this).append("<img src='path' />");` should work.

Comment: @Felix Kling: Now i changed it and used table tag but it is bringing them in single line but it is not deleting

Comment: @Felix Kling: If i add that i am getting many images and it is not deleting.

Comment: @raam: Well, of course you have to adjust `delegate` and the `mouseout` handler (second function passed to `hover`) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is now to use jquery to create dom node on the fly, but instead, create the html statically, and use css and js to show/hide the x mark when users mouse over it.

So, suppose the html struct looks like this:

```
<li class="comment">
  <span class="content">comment text</span>
  <span class="close">x</span>
</li>
```

Then is css:

```
li.comment .content { display: inline-block; }
li.comment .close { display: inline-block; }
li.comment:hover .close { display: none; }
```

For browsers that don't support :hover (IE < 7 for example), you should use jquery to make it work.